# How to implement Single Sign-On in android Applications?

Tags: android, single-sign-on

I am working on 2 android(native) apps and first app is consuming php api and another is asp.net web api. Can i use sso(Onelogin) concept in this scenario?How can i achieve? please provide me some suggestions.I got only java toolkit from https://developers.onelogin.com/saml/java but i want to achieve it on android.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use shared prefs and make them public or you can save  your login flag in a file and that file could be accessed from both applications

Comment: Thanks @Adeel Turk.Two apps have different credentials.so how can i use SSO in this case ?